# How to check if the PC has booted into a different OS?

Tags: windows, boot, uefi

Basically the headline. I want to know if there is a reliable way to see if the PC has booted into a different OS at some time.
We have a few Windows-PCs for our account department, and I noticed this morning that one pc stood slightly different, as if someone accessed the back ports, in addition to it being powered on.
I suspect that one of our workers booted into live linux (possibly to circumvent windows logging or user rights or something) and copied data onto an external drive.
Is there any way to check this? Maybe some kind of UEFI-Logs or something?
Preferrably remote, if possible.

The Windows EventLog doesn't show anything, except for a boot and shutdown in the middle of the night, and another boot this morning, about 4 hours later (but still out of company times).

Comment: If it's possible to copy data by booting into another OS, you got other problems and you should be practicing Data at Rest security principles (like drive encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system firmware generally does not log such things, and Windows itself certainly cannot (due to the fact that it wasn't running at the time).

If a different OS was indeed used, then your network DHCP server's logs might have entries about leases being issued to the machine during the time Windows was supposed to be shut down, possibly even with the 'hostname' field containing an unexpected name. (Assuming the person didn't disconnect the Ethernet cable while doing so.)

But it's not the specific instance of booting a different OS that you should be focusing on – if someone can physically access the computer that way, then they can also just *pull out the whole HDD* and read data out of it using another computer without leaving **any** digital traces whatsoever.

So if the data is sensitive enough to worry about, deploying full-disk encryption (e.g. BitLocker+TPM) should be your first priority; finding ways to detect a different OS is secondary.